# Selenium not finding element - TimeoutException

Tags: python, html, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Selenium to enter data into a field and then scrape data from the results. It enters the data into the field ok and is able to accept the cookie pop up but then cannot find the main-story time element from the resulting page. I've set a wait for the element to be located but it just times out as it cannot be found. The element appears on the page after text is entered into the search box rather than the page reloading so I wonder if this is throwing Selenium off. Any help would be much appreciated! Code is below:

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path= r"/Users/username/anaconda3/bin/geckodriver")
driver.get('https://howlongtobeat.com/#search')

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'onetrust-reject-all-handler')))
driver.find_element(By.ID, 'onetrust-reject-all-handler').click()

inputElement = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'global_search_box')
inputElement.send_keys('The Legend of Zelda: Ocarina of Time')
inputElement.send_keys(u'\ue007')

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'search_list_tidbit center time_100')))
gameTime = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'search_list_tidbit center time_100')[0].text
print(gameTime)
```

Error message is:

```
  File "/Users/username/Documents/Python Projects/Twitter Bot/test HL2B.py", line 19, in <module>
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'search_list_tidbit center time_100')))
  File "/Users/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 90, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: 
Stacktrace:
WebDriverError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.jsm:188:5
NoSuchElementError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.jsm:400:5
element.find/</<@chrome://remote/content/marionette/element.js:292:16
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you done anything about the webdriver error there, might be something wrong with the webdriver, try reinstalling it, maybe that is the problem

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).